# Github User-ID from git log or shortlog

Tags: git, github

I try to get the list of contributors to a file from github. I thought it might be as simple as

```
git shortlog -scne HEAD
```

but this only returns the "real name" and email address of users, but not the github ID/alias to which I could link to.

...and I also couldn't find the right endpoint in the github API

any ideas?

update: xy-problem? I try to display a list of contributors for a given file. It would be great to display the list as a list of user avatars, the same way as guthub does.
Yes, git and github is not the same, but I still think that the mapping between git user and github user has to be hidden somewhere in git. It would be even ok if I had to use the github api.

Comment: 'this only returns the "real name" and email address of users, but not the github ID/alias'—of course. You're running a Git command (which has very little to do with GitHub) on a local repository. It would be strange and concerning if any GitHub-specific information was returned. Furthermore, there's no guarantee that any of the email addresses you find this way are associated with any GitHub account. This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: `Git` uses a username to associate commits with an identity. The Git username is not the same as your `GitHub` username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes, git and github is not the same, but I still think that the mapping between git user and github user has to be hidden somewhere in git.

It is not (hidden in Git).

GitHub uses the *email* (not the committer user name) in order to link it to the:

- actual GitHub account if found with the same email
- the [Gravatar service](https://en.gravatar.com/) which associates a profile picture to an email

Comment: yess! Gravatar is a good approach for displaying the pictures... thanx!

Comment: at least, I can display the pictures this way and I could link to the github page instead of the profile. that should be enough...

Comment: btw: the result can be seen here: https://doctoolchain.github.io/docToolchain/ :-)